# Get part of wallpaper according to current homescreen

Tags: android, android-canvas, live-wallpaper

I'm making a live wallpaper that switches images with various transitions.
But I want to apply the transition only to the part of image that the user can see. And when the transition is complete, the whole wallpaper is drawn.

Any ideas? I don't think I can get which homescreen the user is in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved easily by overriding the `onOffsetsChanged()` method.